# Cannot Post Content to the Facebook Using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce, facebook-app-settings

permissions granted

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [permission] => email [status] => granted ) 
[1] => Array ( [permission] => publish_to_groups [status] => granted ) 
[2] => Array ( [permission] => pages_read_engagement [status] => granted ) 
[3] => Array ( [permission] => pages_manage_posts [status] => granted ) 
[4] => Array ( [permission] => public_profile [status] => granted ) ) )
```

> Error
> (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \ and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission "

Hey guys. I am having problem to Post content on facebook account from php. I have all the credentials right and have all the Permissions granted but still getting the above error. Please guide me I doing something wrong.

Comment: The error message explains what permissions you need to post on a page or a group. There is no way to post on a normal profile.